# Highlight search results in attachments in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook search is quite powerful in that it will find the search term inside the message body and inside the actual attachments (for example an attached PDF file or a text file inside an attached ZIP file)

However this can be a problem as the search can have many hits because of this, and there is no easy way of telling why it matched. Is there a way of doing any of these?:

- Configure Outlook to highlight the search term in the search results pane
- Export the matched message to a file and find the search term inside it with an external tool

Answer (score 0):

By default, Outlook will highlight the search term if a match is found in message subject and body. However, it cannot highlight the search term within attachments. To enable Outlook to highlight the search term within message subject and body, the following option needs to be enabled:

[image]